# how to run several executable using python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have an executable under linux. I have an 8 core processor. I want to run 8 different instances of the same executable with different arguments.

I tried

```
     os.system("process_name args")
```

It does not return until the process is finished.

I want to start 8 different processes from python

If someone could help me please.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are these processes guaranteed to be Python programs, or are you looking to launch generic programs of any type?

Comment: I am looking for the general ones

Comment: they might be but not necessarily python processes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `Popen` objects from the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module.

Note that if you want to redirect I/O to and from the process, this scenario becomes complex because the recommended way to to this is to call [`.communicate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) which you won't be able to use if you want to manage multiple processes simultaneously.  On UNIX-like systems, pipes can be passed to the `select()` system call so you can use the [`select`](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html) module to perform I/O.  This won't work on Windows because the `select()` implementation only accepts socket handles.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I dont want processes to communicate with each other. But should just run stand alone. In this case Popen is the right option?

Comment: `communicate()` is not for processes communicating with each other.  If redirecting I/O through pipes, only the parent process (your Python program) "communicates" with its children.  If you don't redirect child processes' I/O or redirect it to files, then you won't have the "communicate problem" and can just `.poll()` and `.returncode` to see if the process finished.

Comment: `Popen` is the right solution to almost all solutions involving child processes using Python.

Comment: cool, thanks, the output is redirected to the files... One side question... is there any mechanism of knowing when a certain subprocess finishes. Thanks

Comment: @Shan read the manual [Popen.returncode](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode).

Comment: @JonasWielicki better: [`Popen.poll()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) and [`Popen.wait()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait), which set the `returncode`.