# Python subprocess in parallel

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to run many processes in parallel with ability to take stdout in any time. How should I do it? Do I need to run thread for each `subprocess.Popen()` call, a what?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to run several executable using python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724499/how-to-run-several-executable-using-python)

Comment: related: Here's how to [run multiple shell commands (and optionally capture their output) concurrently](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23616229/4279)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do it in a single thread.

Suppose you have a script that prints lines at random times:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#file: child.py
import os
import random
import sys
import time

for i in range(10):
    print("%2d %s %s" % (int(sys.argv[1]), os.getpid(), i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(random.random())
```

And you'd like to collect the output as soon as it becomes available, you could use [`select`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/select#select.select) on POSIX systems as  [@zigg suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743838/python-subprocess-in-parallel/9746401#comment12393687_9743899):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
from select     import select
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# start several subprocesses
processes = [Popen(['./child.py', str(i)], stdout=PIPE,
                   bufsize=1, close_fds=True,
                   universal_newlines=True)
             for i in range(5)]

# read output
timeout = 0.1 # seconds
while processes:
    # remove finished processes from the list (O(N**2))
    for p in processes[:]:
        if p.poll() is not None: # process ended
            print(p.stdout.read(), end='') # read the rest
            p.stdout.close()
            processes.remove(p)

    # wait until there is something to read
    rlist = select([p.stdout for p in processes], [],[], timeout)[0]

    # read a line from each process that has output ready
    for f in rlist:
        print(f.readline(), end='') #NOTE: it can block
```

A more portable solution (that should work on Windows, Linux, OSX) can use reader threads for each process, see [Non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/375427/4279).

Here's [`os.pipe()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os#os.pipe)-based solution that works on Unix and Windows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import io
import os
import sys
from subprocess import Popen

ON_POSIX = 'posix' in sys.builtin_module_names

# create a pipe to get data
input_fd, output_fd = os.pipe()

# start several subprocesses
processes = [Popen([sys.executable, 'child.py', str(i)], stdout=output_fd,
                   close_fds=ON_POSIX) # close input_fd in children
             for i in range(5)]
os.close(output_fd) # close unused end of the pipe

# read output line by line as soon as it is available
with io.open(input_fd, 'r', buffering=1) as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line, end='')
#
for p in processes:
    p.wait()
```

Comment: You seem to multiplex all children's stdout's to a single fd (output_fd) in your last solution. What if 2 children print at the same time, won't that mess up the output (e.g. 'AAA\n' + 'BBB\n' -> 'ABBB\nAA\n')

Comment: @dan3: It is a valid concern. `write`s that are less than `PIPE_BUF` bytes are atomic. Otherwise data from multiple processes may be interleaved. POSIX requires at least 512 bytes. On Linux, `PIPE_BUF` is 4096 bytes.

Comment: Here's a similar question I posted recently here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624056/running-a-secondary-script-in-a-new-terminal would be fantastic if you could help out, thanks in any case.

Comment: I tried the os.pipe solution and it works great, but when I tried to add a progressmeter (like: for each line I get, I increas a number and print the number), then I noticed that I kind of got all the lines at the same time when they all were finished.  Is there something I can do to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: @Gunnar do you get *"all the lines at the same time"* with the code in the answer? (you shouldn't: notice `sys.stdout.flush()` in the child). It may be a block buffering issue in your child process, see [Python C program subprocess hangs at "for line in iter"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20503671/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian  I wrote my own child (and forgot flush) but with flush it works fine, thank you.

Comment: @ When should I use `flush` and why?

Comment: The select approach should perform much better than threads for heavy workloads. I've compiled a quick benchmark here: https://gist.github.com/NF1198/502dca2086825caef82d540f67552090

Answer (score 6):

You can also collect stdout from multiple subprocesses concurrently using [`twisted`](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor

class ProcessProtocol(protocol.ProcessProtocol):
    def outReceived(self, data):
        print data, # received chunk of stdout from child

    def processEnded(self, status):
        global nprocesses
        nprocesses -= 1
        if nprocesses == 0: # all processes ended
            reactor.stop()

# start subprocesses
nprocesses = 5
for _ in xrange(nprocesses):
    reactor.spawnProcess(ProcessProtocol(), sys.executable,
                         args=[sys.executable, 'child.py'],
                         usePTY=True) # can change how child buffers stdout
reactor.run()
```

See [Using Processes in Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/process.html).

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to run a thread for each process. You can peek at the `stdout` streams for each process without blocking on them, and only read from them if they have data available to read.

You *do* have to be careful not to accidentally block on them, though, if you're not intending to.

Comment: I do `p = subprocess.Popen(…)` and then `print p.communicate()[0]` several times. But `communicate()` just waits before process ends.

Comment: Yes, which is why you can't use `communicate()` if you want to use a single thread. There are other ways of getting stdout besides `communicate()`.

Comment: You probably need to look into the [select](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html) module to wait on many subprocesses at once.

Comment: @zigg: note that `select()` on Windows only accepts sockets and any `select()`-based code with pipes is not portable.

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for `process.poll()` to finish, and run other stuff concurrently:

```
import time                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
import sys                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
def ex1() -> None:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    command = 'sleep 2.1 && echo "happy friday"'                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    proc = Popen(command, shell=True, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    while proc.poll() is None:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        # do stuff here                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        print('waiting')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        time.sleep(0.05)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    out, _err = proc.communicate()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    print(out, file=sys.stderr)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    sys.stderr.flush()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    assert proc.poll() == 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
ex1()
```