# "3-way" Python subprocess pipeline: send stdout and stderr to two different processes?

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

Can the "standard" subprocess pipeline technique (e.g. http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) be "upgraded" to two pipelines?

```
# How about
p1 = Popen(["cmd1"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["cmd2"], stdin=p1.stdout)
p3 = Popen(["cmd3"], stdin=p1.stderr)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
p1.stderr.close()
#p2.communicate()  # or p3.communicate()?
```

OK, it's actually a different use case, but the closest starting point seems to be the pipeline example. By the way, how does p2.communicate() in a "normal" pipeline drive p1? Here's the normal pipeline for reference:

```
# From Python docs
output=`dmesg | grep hda`
# becomes
p1 = Popen(["dmesg"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "hda"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

I guess I'm ultimately interested in what kind of "process graphs" (or maybe just trees?) can `communicate()` support, but we'll leave the general case for another day.

**Update**: Here's the baseline functionality. Without communicate(), create 2 threads reading from p1.stdout and p2.stdout. In the main process, inject input via p1.stdin.write(). The question is whether we can drive a 1-source, 2-sink graph using just communicate()

Comment: related: [How do I write stderr to a file while using “tee” with a pipe?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/692000/4279)

Comment: Thanks... but I'm looking to nail down communicate() behaviour in Python

Comment: here's a reverse example: [output from several subprocesses is collected via a single pipe in a single thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9745864/4279) i.e., `n-source -> 1-sink`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use bash's [process substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution):

```
from subprocess import check_call

check_call("cmd1 > >(cmd2) 2> >(cmd3)", shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")
```

It redirects `cmd1`'s stdout to `cmd2` and `cmd1`'s stderr to `cmd3`.

If you don't want to use `bash` then the code in your question should work as is e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from textwrap import dedent

# generate some output on stdout/stderr
source = Popen([sys.executable, "-c", dedent("""
    from __future__ import print_function
    import sys
    from itertools import cycle
    from string import ascii_lowercase

    for i, c in enumerate(cycle(ascii_lowercase)):
        print(c)
        print(i, file=sys.stderr)
""")], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

# convert input to upper case
sink = Popen([sys.executable, "-c", dedent("""
    import sys

    for line in sys.stdin:
        sys.stdout.write(line.upper())
""")], stdin=source.stdout)
source.stdout.close() # allow source to receive SIGPIPE if sink exits

# square input
sink_stderr = Popen([sys.executable, "-c", dedent("""
   import sys

   for line in sys.stdin:
       print(int(line)**2)
""")], stdin=source.stderr)
source.stderr.close() # allow source to receive SIGPIPE if sink_stderr exits

sink.communicate()
sink_stderr.communicate()
source.wait()
```

Comment: Won't the call `sink.communicate()` deadlock if `sink_stderr` fills up the underlying OS pipes? That was the whole point of the `communicate()` function -- it opens up 2 threads, if necessary, to read both `stdout` and `stderr`, avoiding blockage

Comment: @dan3: `.communicate()` doesn't do anything interesting unless `PIPE` is used (and it is *not* used for `sink`, `sink_stderr` processes). You can replace it with a simple `.wait()` call here. I've used `.communicate()` for continuity with the original pipeline recipe and to support a more general case. You could use `Thread(target=sink_stderr.communicate, daemon=True).start()` *if* you use `stdout=PIPE` or `stderr=PIPE` for `sink_stderr` otherwise it is not necessary.

Comment: How about if `sink.communicate()` (which drives `source`) causes the `PIPE` between `source.stderr` and `sink_stderr.stdin` (which is not being read yet) to fill up? That will block `sink.communicate()`.

Comment: There's also a typo in your answer: `source.stdout.close()` should refer to `sink` instead.

Comment: @dan3: 1. `source.stdout.close()` is not a typo. Look at the original pipeline recipe. Make sure you understand why `p1.stdout.close()` is used 2. `sink = Popen(...)` and `sink_stderr = Popen(...)` calls use the redirection at a file descriptor level (at least on POSIX). There is no `PIPE` between `sink.stdin` and `source.stderr`. `stdin=PIPE` and `stdin=some_file_object` are completely different cases. As I've said, you can use even mere `sink.wait()`, `sink_stderr.wait()` calls instead of `.communicate()` in this case.

Comment: OK. I looked in `/proc/.../fd`. There are OS pipes between (source.stdout, sink_stdout.stdin) and (source.stderr, sink_stderr.stdin) (BTW I never said anything about `sink.stdin`, rather `sink_stderr.stdin`). However, as all processes run independently as soon as they are spawned, there is no need for communicate(). The problem arises when there are pipes to/from the main python process -- that's when you need `communicate()`.

Comment: @dan3: you don't need `.communicate()` in this case (`.wait()` is enough). Provide a standalone code example if you think otherwise. The OS pipes you see are due to `source` is created using `stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE` (and some utility pipes that `subprocess` may use internally). `sink` sees something like this: [`os.dup2(source.stdout.fileno(), 0)`](http://goo.gl/4H2gp9) -- it redirects `source`'s stdout  to `sink`'s stdin. As long as `sink` subprocess reads its stdin, nothing blocks.(`sink.communicate()` in another thread won't help `sink` to read its stdin: `sink.stdin is None`).

Comment: @dan3: btw, `sink` and `sink_stderr` are symmetrical in this case. Everything I've said about `sink` applies to `sink_stderr` if you replace `source.stdout` by `source.stderr`. It is obvious if you look at the command in the `check_call(.., shell=True)` call.

Comment: Of course, that's obvious. The crucial part was that .wait() is enough. I was ultimately interested in the general case of subprocess() graphs with multiple sinks, some of which communicate with the main process via std*=PIPE. But discussing this simple example ironed out some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to create a couple of background threads which read the output from one process and then write that into the inputs of several processes:

```
targets = [...] # list of processes as returned by Popen()
while True:
    line = p1.readline()
    if line is None: break
    for p in targets:
        p.stdin.write(line)
```

Comment: I could have two threads reading from p2 and p3 (in the example in my question) and simply inject input via p1.stdin.write(). I'm not looking for something even *lower*-tech :)