# Python3 parallel processes with their own timeouts

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-3.7

I have a requirement where I have to launch multiple applications, get each of their stdout,stderr and these applications run infinitely. The processes do not exchange/share data and are independent of each other. To do variable stress tests, their timeouts might be different.

```
For eg: 
app1 -> 70sec
app2 -> 30sec
.
.
appN -> 20sec
```

If these were multiple apps with one common timeout, I would have wrapped it in a timed while loop and killed all processes in the end.

Here are some approaches I think should work:

1. A timer thread for each app, which reads stdout and as soon as it expires, kills the process. The process is launched within the thread
2. One timer thread that loops through a dictionary of pid/process_objects:end_time for each process and kills the process when its end_time is >= current time

I have tried using asyncio gather, but it doesn't fully meet my needs and I have faced some issues on Windows.

Are there any other approaches that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for the second approach (extended https://stackoverflow.com/a/9745864/286990).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import io
import os
import sys
from subprocess import Popen
import threading
import time
import psutil

def proc_monitor_thread(proc_dict):
    while proc_dict != {}:
        for k,v in list(proc_dict.items()):
            if time.time() > v:
                print("killing " + str(k))
                m = psutil.Process(k)
                m.kill()
                del proc_dict[k]
        time.sleep(2)

pros = {} 

ON_POSIX = 'posix' in sys.builtin_module_names

# create a pipe to get data
input_fd, output_fd = os.pipe()

# start several subprocesses
st_time = time.time()
for i in ["www.google.com", "www.amd.com", "www.wix.com"]:
    proc = Popen(["ping", "-t", str(i)], stdout=output_fd,
                   close_fds=ON_POSIX) # close input_fd in children

    if "google" in i:
        pros[proc.pid] = time.time() + 5
    elif "amd" in i:
        pros[proc.pid] = time.time() + 8
    else:
        pros[proc.pid] = time.time() + 10

os.close(output_fd)
x = threading.Thread(target=proc_monitor_thread, args=(pros,))
x.start()

# read output line by line as soon as it is available
with io.open(input_fd, 'r', buffering=1) as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line, end='')
#

print("End")
x.join()
```

Answer (score 2):

Second option is pretty production-ready. Have a control loop where you poll for processes to complete and kill them if they are timing out